# Xamarin.Forms: How to hide the Navigation Bar Separator on iOS devices?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have changed the default color of the navigation bar by using these codes in `app.xaml` as I am unable to make it transparent on iOS devices:

```
<Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
            <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="#0a82b8" />
            <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="#ffffff" />
</Style>
```

Now, there is an unnecessary navigation bar separator on iOS:

[image]

On Microsoft's official website, it says these codes can be helpful:

> This platform-specific hides the separator line and shadow that is at
>   the bottom of the navigation bar on a NavigationPage. It's consumed in
>   XAML by setting the NavigationPage.HideNavigationBarSeparator bindable
>   property to false:
>
> ```
> <NavigationPage ...
>                 xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
>                 ios:NavigationPage.HideNavigationBarSeparator="true">
>
> </NavigationPage>
> ```
>
> Alternatively, it can be consumed from C# using the fluent API:
>
> ```
> using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
> using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;
>
> public class iOSTitleViewNavigationPageCS : Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage
> {
>     public iOSTitleViewNavigationPageCS()
>     {
>         On<iOS>().SetHideNavigationBarSeparator(true);
>     }
> }
> ```

Source: [Hiding the Navigation Bar Separator on a NavigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/platform-specifics/consuming/ios#hiding-the-navigation-bar-separator-on-a-navigationpage)

The problem is that when I want to paste the `ios:NavigationPage.HideNavigationBarSeparator="true"` property into the `<NavigationPage>`tag, it gives this error:

> No property, bindable property, or event found for 'HideNavigationBarSeparator', or mismatching type between value and property.

My full codes are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.App" x:Class="My.App.MainPage">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Title="Menu" BackgroundColor="#0a82b8" Icon="menu.png">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <ListView x:Name="navigationDrawerList" RowHeight="55" SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="#ffffff" ItemSelected="OnMenuItemSelected">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <!-- Main design for our menu items -->
                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="20,10,0,10" Spacing="20">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="Large" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="#28DDFF" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            ios:NavigationPage.HideNavigationBarSeparator="true">
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

[Here](http://chettrigroup.xyz/notes/2018/09/26/xamarin-forms-masterdetail-navigation-page-customizable-tutorial-4) is the tutorial which I followed for the MasterDetail navigation. The file which has `<NavigationPage>` tag is named as `MainPage.xaml`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a custom renderer to hide that shadow:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationPage))]
namespace CustomNavigationPage.iOS
{
    public class CustomNavigationPage : NavigationRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIKit.UIImage(), UIKit.UIBarMetrics.Default);
            NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIKit.UIImage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much! @BrunoCaceiro

Comment: this doesn't work for MAUI. You have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

While you have accepted the answer, this one is more precise - you haven't followed the instructions that you have pasted from the site as you have ommited this line:

```
xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
```

Answer (score 1):

Place  `UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();`   inside the `public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)`  method within AppDelegate.cs file.   AppDelegate.cs resides within the iOS project of Xamarin.Forms